# How can I deploy https://github.com/docker/compose-on-kubernetes on IBM Cloud Kubernetes service?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, ibm-cloud, iks, ibm-cloud-kubernetes

as in AWK o GKE, anyway to deploy compose (https://github.com/docker/compose-on-kubernetes) on IBM Cloud Kubernetes service.

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of the readme file exists section [Deploying Compose on Kubernetes](https://github.com/docker/compose-on-kubernetes#deploying-compose-on-kubernetes).

There are manuals for `minikube`, `azure`, `gcp`, `microk8s`... but in general, they all follow same path. Run install for your OS against `etcd` endpoint.